# Firebase UserCredential and initializeApp error in my flutter app

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Am having this problem in my app where UserCredential is showing an error like this
[image]

I have **firebase_auth** installed already in my pubspec.yaml file and imported `import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';` but it still keeps throwing this error and the same happen to my `await Firebase.initializeApp();` in main.dart. I don't know where this issue is coming from, I even upgraded my flutter to flutter 2.0 and it still persist.

**Pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.0
  firebase_auth:
  provider: ^5.0.0
  flutter_switch: ^0.2.0
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.12+4
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+17
  flutter_image_compress: ^0.7.0
  cached_network_image: ^2.5.0
  image_cropper: ^1.3.1
  intl: ^0.17.0
  http: ^0.12.2
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  animations: ^2.0.0
  smooth_star_rating: ^1.1.1
  csc_picker: ^0.0.4
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
```

Please is there something am missing because it was working yesterday but today it isn't even after created a new folder and moving everything to it. Please help and if you need more explanation you can ask.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Actually i don't think the problem is from the code cause it was working fine but this morning it just started doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `firebase_core` as dependency. As all the firebase product depends on it.